# ID is taking null value when website is live but working fine on local host

Tags: sql, asp.net

In my aspx website primary key i.e id is being failed to insert in database and taking null value when its live on web but its working fine on local host.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nblqs.png)

Comment: is the id set to AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: yeah it is set to auto increament

Comment: What is your insert query. Could you write the code please.

Comment: Every thing is working fine on local host so there is no problem in query i guess

Comment: i guess then it is your table setup. You missed something setting up on your web server. Some setting in your table is not the same as local host. Try a simple select query on that table on the web and see if it goes through or not.

Comment: its fetching data alright . Problem is in insertion

Comment: not sure how you set up your table. But the server could be case sensitive while local host is not so strict. Hard to say. I could probably give you a better advice if I saw your actual insert query / table layout. Without atleast that I am not sure anyone could help you.

Comment: public static bool addbranch(branch b)
    {
        ctownDataContext db = new ctownDataContext();
        int count = (from x in db.GetTable<branch>()
                     where x.name == b.name || x.brachno == b.brachno
                     select new {
                         x.Id }).Count();
        if (count == 0)
        {
            db.branches.InsertOnSubmit(b);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }